# .apk IIS webserver download error on android 2.3.x

Tags: android, iis-7.5

We have a IIS webserver set up to distribute .apk files for an application we are developing. We are distributing files via a direct link to file path in IIS we are not using any special pages to download the files, we are just sending the direct link and opening it in the browsers starts the file download.

I have set up the server to handle .apk files with a mime type "application/vnd.adroid.package-archive" after reading this site.

Downloading files on a desktop machine or any android device that is 3.2+ seems to work just fine.  However so far any android device running 2.3.x seems to be failing to download.  the download immediately errors out and if you goto the download manager it says "cannot download. The content is not supported by this phone."  It seems that android 2.3.x devices are not recognizing the file as a .apk file.

I'm at a loss as to what is causing this issue as its working on desktop browsers (IE, firefox) and new android devices (3.2+).

the webserver is running a Win 2008 R2 backend with IIS 7.5

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm it looks like android 2.3.x doesnt like the mime type "application/vnd.adroid.package-archive" I changed the mime type for .apk to "application/octet-Stream" and it seems to be serving the file correctly to all devices.  I will do some further testing to confirm and update.