# Perl code output behave differently in IIS and Apache

Tags: android, perl, apache, iis, http-headers

I have perl script which is setting header with following command

```
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv\n\n";
```

This script is behaving differently when deployed on web server IIS and Apache.

When the code is deployed on apache web server, I am able to download the file test.csv on android mobile.

But When the same script is deployed on IIS server, download is always unsuccessful on android mobile.

Note: but the download work like charm in any desktop browser for both web server.

Following is response header from IIS

```
(Status-Line)   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Server Microsoft-IIS/6.0
 Content-Disposition    attachment; filename=test.csv
 X-Powered-By   ASP.NET
 Date   Thu, 31 Jan 2013 10:10:59 GMT
 Connection close
```

Following is response header from Apache

```
(Status-Line)   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Date   Thu, 31 Jan 2013 10:12:33 GMT
 Server Apache/2.2.22 (Win32)
 Content-Disposition    attachment; filename=test.csv
 Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100
 Connection Keep-Alive
 Transfer-Encoding  chunked
 Content-Type   text/plain
```

can any one help me in resolving this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show more code?  Are you using a CGI module or other framework?

Comment: I am not using any cgi module, it is simple perl code (no framework).
It has only this much code you can say :)

Comment: As you can see, the Content-Disposition header is the same, so why do you think that's the problem? What are you using to download? How is it unsuccessful?

Comment: @Len Jaffe, He's sending from CGI, not receiving.

Comment: When something works under Apache and fails under IIS, I typically blame IIS as a bad job and stop using it.  But I'd hypothesize that the Transfer-Encoding header is significant.  You might need to set that header manually to insure that IIS passes it.

Comment: @Amit Vikram, Did you try specifying a Content-Type? Or how about a Content-Length since it's not chunked on IIS?

Comment: @Len Jaffe, You can't set TE:chunk without actually chunking the content.

Comment: @ikegami - apache is doing it.

Comment: @Len Jaffe, I'm suggesting that doing what you suggested would definitely not work.

Comment: @Len Jaffe, Yes, Apache is doing it, which is why it's adding the header. Your logic is quite invalid if you think you can concluded that adding the header will cause IIS to chunk your data. Quite the opposite, telling the server the response is chunked would surely cause Apache to stop chunking it, leading to a bad response.

Comment: Could it be a line ending issue? Might you need to use `\r\n` on IIS?

Comment: @ikegami: " I'm suggesting that doing what you suggested would definitely not work" ... If I had a nickel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your support.

I tried for following perl code and it helped me  to resolve the issue

```
# Set the header using following way
print "Content-Type: text/plain", "\n";
print "Content-length: $length", "\n";
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv\n\n";
```

note : $length is a variable which store the file content length as shown below

```
my $csv = "testing";
my $length = length $csv;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution.  It is valid to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that other people are also having trouble downloading from IIS servers to Android:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33362

[.apk IIS webserver download error on android 2.3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020169/apk-iis-webserver-download-error-on-android-2-3-x)

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/Android/Q_27592118.html

I don't think it's a Perl problem.  I didn't see a solution, though.

Comment: The first case uses basic HTTP auth. @Amit Vikram, are you using that?

Comment: A comment at the second link suggests that setting the Content-Type will do the trick.

Comment: @ikegami i tried for different content type but it did not helped me.